# Correct notation of ghost notes depending on note duration

Tags: notation

Chords, notes and rests can generally be notated to show a duration of 1, 1/2, 1/4 etc. beats but how do I do that for ghost notes - i.e. those with an 'x' as a head. I can find examples of a quarter note and less that use flags on the step but nothing greater than a quarter.

For example, in 4/4 I can fill a measure with two half notes...

```
 |   |
o|  o|
```

but this doesn't work

```
 |   |
x|  x|
```

It looks like, and is, two quarters. I would have to put a quarter rest between and after the two notes but that's not really what I mean.

Comment: A ghost note is generally a percussive effect, so a half-note doesn't really make sense. Could you describe what you're going for musically? There may be another more standard way to express it.

Comment: I think you won't be able to reply to the comment, but you can edit your post to include the musical context.

Comment: Take a look at the examples above. In the first I play two half beats which fill the four beat measure. In the 2nd example I want to express the same but as a percussive sound so I would need to place two 1/4 beat rests to complete the measure, something like "x| r x| r" but that would indicate that the sound should be cut off after the first and 3rd quarters

Comment: What instrument?

Comment: I'm writing an application to support learning to sight read so it could apply to any instrument. There's a step by step progression so starting just with rhythm, pitch is not relevant so ghost notes would be appropriate. All sheet music I've seen ghost notes of 1/4, 1/8, 1/16 are used liberally but not 1/2 or whole notes - it's not the end of the world if there is no correct way to notate it - I'll invent my own

Comment: In Sibelius a cross-headed half-note will have a cross inside a circle as the note head.

Comment: In some circumstances a ghost note is notated by putting brackets around the note head - e.g. a "ghosted" minim would look the same as a normal minim, except with brackets. This is most usually done in drum kit notation though, especially as this could be misconstrued as something like a cue in pitched notation

Comment: My experience is that ghost notes are denoted with brackets/parentheses around the note head, **not** by using an alternate note head shape. I would generally reserve alternate note heads for specific kit pieces (for drums), muted notes (e.g., guitar), spoken words in a vocal score, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some alternative suggestions to what Aaron proposed, which I was able to make in MuseScore – in case you wanted to notate ghost notes for a pitched instrument. In the second measure I selected Note Head: Cross, and Head Type: Half.

[image]

Comment: If you upvote this, upvote Aaron's as well, the second example is demonstration of what he suggested in the comments.

Comment: I did upvote Aarons. Great solution! Take the rest of the day off.

Comment: @user1079505 - I access Music Stack Exchange almost exclusively on mobile, so Aaron's answer displays nothing to me graphically, and I do not understand enough of its code to verify it. Therefore, I cannot in good honesty upvote it.

Comment: @Dekkadeci so ABC on SE doesn't work on mobile? :( What Aaron proposed was to write rhythm on staff with only single line, thus without note pitches, which is an excellent solution if you want to notate rhythm only.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I was just able to render ABC js on mobile by selecting desktop site view from Chrome menu.

Answer (score 7):

I've seen this symbol used in some cases:

[image: ![Half ghost note]

(It's just the diamond head that's important.)  In percussion music, it often represents a cymbal clash, which lasts longer than most drum sounds.  You can also remove the stem for a whole note.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're writing rhythm only, and the pitches are not important, the standard option is to use a single-line percussion staff.

```
X:0
T:Single-line staff example
M:4/4
K: C clef=perc stafflines=1
L:1/4
V:V1 stafflines=1
[V:V1]B B/2B/2 B B/2B/2 | B2 B2 |]
```

Comment: Thx Aaron. I guess that's the way I'll have to proceed.

Answer (score 4):

In percussion it is common to see anti accent marks (i.e. ghost notes) in sheet music:
[image]

Above the notes surrounded by parenthesis would be the ghost notes.  Part of the reason for this, is that cymbals in percussion music all use X's already.  The [Ghost Note Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_note) has a good section about this.